# Swift Pattern Matching - Switch, downcasting, and optional binding in a single statement

Tags: swift, pattern-matching, optional-binding

Is there a way to consolidate the `switch` statement below to include the optional binding?

A little background context...

First here's my result type:

```
enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case failure(Swift.Error)
}
```

An extension on Facebook's SDK:

```
func start(_ completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Any>) -> Void) -> FBSDKGraphRequestConnection
{
    return start() { (_, response, error) in
        switch (response, error) {
        case (.some(let result), .none):
            completionHandler(Result(value: result))

        case (.none, .some(let error)):
            completionHandler(Result(error: error))

        case (.none, .none), (.some, .some):
            preconditionFailure("Unexpected State")
        }
    }
}
```

And, finally, the bit of code I'm trying to refactor. My goal is to avoid the duplicate `self.present(error:)` code:

```
_ = FBSDKGraphRequest.emailRequest().start() { (result: Result<Any>) in

    switch result {
    case .success (let value as [ String : Any ]):
        ...
        if let email = value["email"] as? String {
            ...
        }
        else {
            self.present(error: Error(.facebookOther))
        }

    default:
        self.present(error: Error(.facebookOther))
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite there.  This eliminates the duplication, but it doesn't give you the optional binding: `switch result {
case .success (let value as [ String : Any ]) where value["email"] is String:
    print("email: \(value["email"]!)")
    
default:
    self.present(error: Error(.facebookOther))
}`

Comment: Could you please elaborate which duplication are you trying to avoid? Is it optional binding of `email`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can eliminate the duplication with a `switch` and optionally bind `email`, but you can with an `if`:

```
if case .success(let value as [String : Any]) = result, let email = value["email"] as? String {
    print("email: \(email)")
} else {
    self.present(error: Error(.facebookOther))
}
```

---

The best you can do with a `switch` is to avoid the duplication by adding a `where` clause, but you miss out on the optional binding of `email`:

```
switch result {
case .success (let value as [ String : Any ]) where value["email"] is String:
    let email = value["email"] as! String
    print("email: \(email)")
default:
    self.present(error: Error(.facebookOther))
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Thank you. My brain could just not un-see a `switch` statement!